# Grafana configuration reference

Tags: azure-active-directory, yaml, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I have a Kubernetes cluster with kube-prometheus-stack (which includes Grafana) deployed via Helm. I am trying to set up single sign on (SSO) to Grafana using AzureAD. I've found the Grafana configuration pages (https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/setup-grafana/configure-grafana and https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/azuread/) and I think I have an initial idea of what I need to add to my Helm chart's values.yaml file.

There are some details, however, that I am not sure about. If I had access to the "schema" for this configuration, that might help me figure this out. Unfortunately, I have been unable to find anything that defines this. There are examples, but I cannot find anything that describes what the fields mean. Also, keep in mind that everything I have found shows examples for the grafana.ini file. I need to "translate" this to YAML for the values.yaml file used by the Helm chart.

Here is an example:

```
...
[auth.azuread]
name = Azure AD
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = true
client_id = APPLICATION_ID
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
scopes = openid email profile
auth_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
token_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token
allowed_domains =
allowed_groups =
role_attribute_strict = false
```

I have translated this into the following YAML:

```
  auth.azuread:
    name: Azure AD
    enabled: true
    allow_sign_up: true
    client_id: APPLICATION_ID
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
    scopes: openid email profile
    auth_url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    token_url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token
    allowed_domains:
    allowed_groups:
    role_attribute_strict: false
```

I suspect that `scopes` expects a list based on its plurality, but how can I be sure? Also, what are the valid values? Apparently `openid`, `email` and `profile` are valid, but what do these values represent and are there others? On a similar note, what do `allowed_domains` and `allowed_groups` expect?

I've tried to find a reference for the Grafana configuration data structure and definition, but have not had any luck. Does anyone have an idea where (if) this can be found?

Comment: Could you include more details like what exactly you need? Have you created one Azure AD application?

Comment: I don't know what I need. Having some idea of what how this configuration data structure is defined would help me understand what I need to provide. What is required and what is not? What are the valid values for fields (e.g. `scopes`, etc.)? Right now it's a black box.

Comment: Actually, you need to register one Azure AD application in which you have to add **API permissions** like [this](https://i.imgur.com/0XQ93gg.png). These are the values of **`scope`** which are required to fetch signed in user's details.

Comment: We do have an AzureAD app set up, although I don't know the details about how it's configured on that end (I don't have access or know what to do).

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that you have already figured out the answer to your question and if not, here's some reference:

In Azure AD, the scopes serve the following purposes:

`openid`: Confirms the user's identity and acquires a basic user profile without disclosing personal information.

`email`: Provides authorization to access the user's main email address.

`profile`: Fetches fundamental profile details about the user, encompassing their name and preferred username.

The `allowed_groups` configuration in `grafana.ini` allow access only to users within specified groups, while others encounter a login error. To enable access for multiple groups, separate the object IDs with commas, utilizing Azure AD object IDs. Additionally, you can manage access levels for each AD security group using app roles.

`allowed_domains` limits access within the organization for the specified domain. Every user in the organization gets viewer access by default